# How to set crispy_forms' Layout to render a Django DecimalField with exactly 2 decimal places?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

In a *Django* form `my_form` with a *DecimalField* I would like to show in that field a float value with exactly two decimal places. The definition of this field is

```
fee = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=7)
```

and in the html template I render the form with *crispy_forms* as

```
{% crispy my_form %}
```

If the decimal places of `fee` have any value not 0 everything works fine (e.g. 70.12 --> "70.12"). But if I they are 0 only the integer part of this value is shown (70.0 --> "70").

Is there any way to convince *crispy_forms* to display values **always** with two decimal places (70.0 --> "70.00")? I searched for hours in the world wide web for a solution but found really nothing.

Thx in advance.
Humbalan

Answer (score 0):

Try applying |floatformat:2 filter tag

Comment: Thx Andrei, I know about floatformat if I render the form explicitly with html, but I let render it by the crispy_forms macro {% crispy my_form %}. So I wonder if I could apply floatformat somwhere In crispy_forms.layout.

Comment: ah, sorry, I was mindless. In this tutorial [https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html) I'd seen that the author used a simple template tag with |as_crispy_field, so I thought you could simply chain another filter there.